# Can a weakly inaccessible non-weakly-Mahlo cardinal carry a $\kappa$-complete, $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

An ideal $I$ on a regular cardinal $\kappa$ is said to be $\mu$-saturated if whenever a family $\langle S_\alpha \mid \alpha<\lambda\rangle$ of subsets of $\kappa$ is such that each $S_\alpha\notin I$ and for $\alpha\neq \beta$, $S_\alpha\cap S_\beta\in I$, then $\lambda<\mu$.

**Question**: If $\kappa$ is weakly inaccessible and carries a $\kappa$-complete, $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal, must $\kappa$ be weakly Mahlo,

It is known, for instance, that if $\kappa$ carries a $\kappa$-complete, $\kappa$-saturated ideal, then $\kappa$ must be weakly Mahlo. Further, $\kappa$ *may* carry a $\kappa$-complete, $\kappa^+$-saturated ideal if $\kappa$ is a successor cardinal; these results are summarized in [2]. However, those consistency results for $\kappa$ inaccessible all have that $\kappa$ is Mahlo.

On face value, the argument in [1], Theorem 7.57, doesn't address the question either, as in the final model, there are no inaccessible cardinals.

[1] Foreman, M. (2010). Ideals and Generic Elementary Embeddings. In Handbook of Set Theory (pp. 885–1147). Dordrecht: Springer Netherlands. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-5764-9_14

[2] Kunen, K. (1978). Saturated Ideals. Journal of Symbolic Logic, 43(1), 65–76. https://doi.org/10.2307/2271949

Comment: Have you checked the following: suppose $\kappa$ is an almost huge cardinal and there exists a $\kappa$-c.c forcing $P$ that forces $\kappa$ to be non-Mahlo (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168460/destroying-the-mahloness-of-a-cardinal-with-kappa-c-c-forcing), suppose the almost huge-ness is witnessed by $j: V\to M$ such that $\lambda=j(\kappa)$ and $|j(\lambda)|=\lambda$, then do $P*Coll(\kappa, <\lambda)$ (should be analogous to Kunen's analysis).

Comment: I haven't but on the face of it this doesn't look unreasonable to me. Is the the almost huge embedding with $|j(\lambda)|=\lambda$ what guarantees the appropriate absorption of $P*Coll(\kappa,<\lambda)$ to $j(P)$?

Comment: No but you can always force again. In $V^P$, $j(P)/P$ is $\lambda$-cc, and $Coll(\kappa, <\lambda)$ is $\lambda$-Knaster, hence in $V^{P*Coll(\kappa, <\lambda)}$, you can force with $(j(P)/P)^{V^P}$ ($\lambda$-c.c), so in $V^{P*Coll*j(P)/P}$, first lift j to $j^1: V^P\to M^{j(P)}$, then use $|j(\lambda)|=\lambda$ to build a generic over $M$ for $j^1(Coll(\kappa, <\lambda))$ consistent with ${j^1}''G$ ($G\subset Coll(\kappa, <\lambda)$ generic over $V^P$).

Comment: @Otto It‘s not that simple or automatic.  One has to engineer $P$ so that $j(P)$ absorbs $Col(\kappa,<\lambda)$

Comment: In general you can't in this situation. If $j(P)$ were to absorb $Coll(\kappa, <\lambda)$, then by elementarity, $P$ will have to force $\kappa$ to be a successor cardinal, which is not what we want.